# Trying to use zfill and increment characters with Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, increment

Hello lovely stackoverflowians!
I am fairly new to programming. Only have been programming a little under 2 months using CS50 which uses C and MITx Python. I went on Codewars and am trying to solve a problem where you basically get an id and then come out with a license plate number like this aaa001...aaa999, aab001...zzz999
if you catch my drift. For some reason my code compiles but when I run it I get this error.
File "/Users/pauliekennedy/Desktop/temp.py", line 9, in find_the_number_plate
a_str = (a_numb.zfill(3), range(0, 10))

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'zfill'

Because of this I am not able to test my code. If you could help me with this problem I would be much appreciated. As well, if you have anything to say about my code in general, tips, advice how to make it better, and if it will achieve this goal at all. Here is my code thanks again all.

````
    #set number to 1 to start
    a_numb = 1
    #incrementing loop when 999 go back set back 0
    while a_numb <1001:
        a_numb += 1
        a_str = str(a_numb)
        # giving the number 00 or just 0 in front
        if a_numb < 100:
            a_str = (a_numb.zfill(3), range(0, 10))
        #resetting the number back to 1
        if a_numb == 999:
            a_numb = 1
    # Setting i to 0 and incrementing the characters
    i = 0
    ch = 'a'
    ch2 = 'a'
    ch3 = 'a'
    #looping through alphabet
    for i in range(26):
        ch = chr(ord(ch) + 1) 
        print(ch)
        if i == 26:
            i = 0
            if ch == 'z':
                ch2 = chr(ord(ch) + 1)
                if ch == 'z' & ch2 == 'z':
                    ch3(ord(ch) + 1)
    # Adding results together and returning the string of them all
    letter_plate = str(ch3 + ch2 + ch)
    plate = str(a_numb) + str(letter_plate)
    return plate```
````

Comment: You meant `a_str.zfill(3)`

Comment: The function zfill() is used on a string, see the docs (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_zfill.asp). You most likely want to use a_str instead of a_numb to call the function on, since a_str is of type string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider using [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) instead:

```
def find_the_number_plate(customer_id):
    number_part = customer_id % 999 + 1
    customer_id //= 999
    letter_part = ['a', 'a', 'a']
    i = 0
    while customer_id:
        letter_part[i] = chr(ord('a') + customer_id % 26)
        customer_id //= 26
        i += 1
    return f"{''.join(letter_part)}{number_part:03}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use product from itertools to form the license plate numbers from 3 letters and numbers from 1 to 999 formatted with leading zeros:

```
from itertools import product

letter  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
numbers = (f"{n:03}" for n in range(1,1000))
plates  = [*map("".join,product(letter,letter,letter,numbers))]

for plate in plates: print(plate)

aaa001
aaa002
aaa003
aaa004
aaa005
aaa006
aaa007
aaa008
...
```

If you only need to access a license place at a specific index, you don't have to generate the whole list.  You can figure out which plate number will be at a given index by decomposing the index in chunks of 999,26,26,26 corresponding to the available option at each position/chunk of the number.

```
def plate(i):
    letter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    result = f"{i%999+1:03}"
    i //= 999
    for _ in range(3):
       result = letter[i%26] + result
       i //= 26
    return result
```

output:

```
for i in range(10):print(plate(i))

aaa001
aaa002
aaa003
aaa004
aaa005
aaa006
aaa007
aaa008
aaa009
aaa010

plate(2021)  # aac024
```

Comment: The letter part in your `def plate` one is reversed from what is expected in some cases. e.g. for `i=1487` the output should be `baa489` while your current code gives `aab489`.

Comment: The order is lexicographical. So is the OP's example where aaa999, aab001 are consecutive.  baa489 would be at index 675812 in that order.   Both the list and the function give the same order.

Comment: Sorry I actually only tried the second function, regardless then both the output from your list and function currently fail for a bunch of test cases for the reason I mention above from the site OP mentions they are [using](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5f25f475420f1b002412bb1f/train/python).

Comment: I didn't look at the link. I guess the function could be adjusted to return `result[2:-1:-1]+result[3:]` to meet the half backward order requirement.  And the question should be corrected to avoid suggesting the wrong order with `aaa001...aaa999, aab001...zzz999`